# What are the minimum fees for Ardor and Child Chain bundlers like Ignis and others?

Tags: transaction-fees, ardor, ignis, bundler, child-chain

I couldn't find a chart of what the Ardor and related child chain fees are. What is the cost in Ardr, Ignis, and other child chains during mining/bundling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fee structure can be found on this [fees chart for Ardor](https://www.jelurida.com/sites/default/files/ArdorFees.pdf) provided by Jelurida, the developers of Ardor.

There is no fee to mine, and no fee to bundle. But when you bundle, you are receiving child chain tokens, such as IGNIS, BITSWIFT, or AEUR, and then paying the forgers (miner-equivalent for Ardor) the respective fee in ARDR based on the chart that I linked. As a bundler, you get to set the rate that you would like, the maximum amount of fees you're willing to pay, and other settings.

Running a bundler is also a great way to convert ARDR into child chain coins because unlike using the Coin Exchange feature on Ardor where you can trade child chain coins and ARDR against each other, you won't be paying fees yourself for making the trade. It's not as fast though since it depends on the transaction volume on that respective child chain.

[image]

---

### Transaction Type / Fee (ARDR) / Reasons

- Default Ardor fee 1 permanent transaction
- Default Child Chain fee 0.01 prunable transaction
- New account fee 1 creates permanent global entity
- Balance leasing 0.1 Ardor chain only, not frequently used
- Ardor Coin Exchange 0.5 permanent transaction
- Asset issuance 100 create permanent global entity, Ignis chain only, not frequently used, need to reduce scam assets
- Singleton asset issuance 1 + 1 per 32b Ignis chain only, more frequently used, but still creates global permanent entity
- Asset increase 10 Ignis chain only, rarely used
- Dividend payment 0.1 needs processing, not frequently used
- Set asset control 10 Ignis chain only, not frequently used, asset issuers only
- Set account control 1 Ignis chain only, not frequently used
- Cloud data upload 0.1 + 0.01 per 1kb prunable, but takes space
- Poll creation 1 + 0.1 per option > 20 + 0.2 per 32b > 288b not frequently used, need to keep until poll is over, takes space
- Phasing approval 0.01 per approved tx needs processing
- Account info 1 + 1 per 32b permanent, Ignis only, rarely used
- Set account property 0.1 + 0.1 per 32b permanent, Ignis only, not frequently used
- Alias assignment 1 + 1 per 32b creates permanent unique entity, not frequently used
- Shuffling (total) 0.12 takes space, but prunable, not frequently used
- Shuffling penalty 10 IGNIS, 10 Bitswift must be affordable, but not negligible
- Currency issuance 4 / 100 / 2500 creates permanent unique entity, not frequently used
- Marketplace listing 0.2 + 0.2 per 32b takes space, need to keep until delisting, not frequently used
- Marketplace delivery 0.1 + 0.2 per 32b takes space, need to keep Permanent message 0.1 + 0.1 per 32b permanent
- Prunable message 0.01 per 1k prunable
- Phasing appendix 0.01 balance independent, 0.2 balance dependent + 0.01 per 32b size depends on size and complexity, needs processing
- Composite phasing appendix 0.02 + 0.02 per 32b + per poll fees determined by phasing complexity Referenced Tx deposit 10 refundable